# how to change the background color of the div when a user selects particular color in the color picker?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change the background color of div when a user picks the particular color in the color picker. For example If user selects red from the color picker then the background should change into red. The important point here is we shouldn't use jquery to change this. Instead of using jquery,(can use javascript) the css styles of that particular div should be added to the div when user selects particular color.

```
<div class="sideBar">
<ul>
<li> content 1 </li>
<li> content 2 </li>
<li> content 3 </li>
<li> content 4 </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="mainBar">
<form>
<input type="color" name="colorPicker" id="colorPicker" title="Choose Color" />
</form>
</div>

css :

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.sideBar
{
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    height: 500px;
    background: blue;
}
.mainBar
{
    width: 100% ;
    height: 500px;
    background: #96F ;
}
```

thanks in advance..

Comment: Without javascript you would have to write your own `PHP` logic that happes after a form submit.

Comment: No javascript at all? or just no jquery?

Comment: @rob w can use javascript... how to achieve this ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Color Dynamic</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>
<body>
<div class="sideBar">
<ul>
<li> content 1 </li>
<li> content 2 </li>
<li> content 3 </li>
<li> content 4 </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="mainBar"> 
<input type="color" name="colorPicker" id="colorPicker" title="Choose Color" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var colorPick = $('#colorPicker');
var styleElt =  '<style></style>';
colorPick.on('change', function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
    var selectedVal = $(this).val();
    $('head').html('<style>.sideBar{background-color:'+ selectedVal +'}</style>');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10):

You will need Javascript to do this properly.

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/XZ6Sg/

HTML:

```
<input type="color" name="colorPicker" id="colorPicker" title="Choose Color" />
<div></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var picker = document.getElementById('colorPicker');
var box = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
picker.addEventListener('change', function(){
   box.style.backgroundColor = this.value; 
})
```

Comment: is there any alternative for doing the same thing.. ? Instead of writing box.style.backgroundColor = this.value ; , i need to override this style to the existing stylesheet

Comment: I don't know i understand what you want. When you don't use `!important` in your css this script above will always override the rule you've defined within your css file (it will attach `<div style="background-color: ...;"></div>` to the html. When you want to use pre defined styles based on the users color selection, you will have to implement a logic to compare the user color selection with your css, which would be a mess.

Comment: what i want is , that style should be internally added to the div whenever the user selects colors from the color picker

Comment: Please write an example of what you want. Do you want to let the value of the selected color to appear within the div?